# Using an active 'li' element to determine a video's source file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried creating a small video library where one div is split into two parts: 1) a menu on the left with the titles of the movies and 2) the rest of the div on the right being a video window that changes it's video source according to the selected title on the menu. I gave the li elements that housed the titles id's and used jQuery/JavaScript to retrieve the title and to assign a new video source based on that title, but it isn't working and I also can't claim to completely understand what I've done. The code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="miyazaki">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="Gulliver">Gulliver's Travels</a></li>
      <li><a id="Howl">Howl's Moving Castle</a></li>
      <li><a id="Kiki">Kiki's Delivery Service</a></li>
      <li><a id="Castle">Castle of Cagoliostro</a></li>
      <li><a id="Totoro">"My Neighbor Totoro</a></li>
      <li><a id="Ponyo">Ponyo</a></li>
      <li><a id="Mononoke">"Princess Mononoke</a></li>
      <li><a id="Spirited">Spirited Away</a></li>
      <li><a id="Sky">The Sky's Castle Laputa</a></li>
      <li><a id="Nausicaa">Nausicaa Valley of the Wind</a></li>
      <li><a id="Cat">"The Cat Returns</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Hayato() {
var movie = $("ul.menu li a.active");
if (movie.id == Gulliver || movie.id == null || movie.id == "") {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Gulliver.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Howl) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Howl.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Kiki) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Kiki.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Castle) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Castle.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Totoro) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Totoro.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Ponyo) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Ponyo.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Mononoke) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Mononoke.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Spirited) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Spirited.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Sky) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Sky.mkv
}
else if (movie.id == Nausicaa) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Nausicaa.mkv
}
else (movie.id == Cat) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('window').video.source.src = Cat.mkv
}
}
```

I'm not entirely sure this code is the best way to go about solving my problem, but it's the most logical progression I can think of.

Comment: All your strings are actually no strings ...

Comment: so much copy paste.... use a data attribute and read the data attribute when you click the element. And getElementsByClassName returns an HTML Collection and you treat it as one element. And strings, need quotes

Comment: You can compact it into 1 line. Using the data attribute : https://jsfiddle.net/3utcetpn/

Answer (score 1):

This can all be condensed down considerably since most of the code stays the same in all cases. Also, your closing `<ul>` isn't a close tag and you are missing a closing `<div>`.

```js
// Get all the <a> elements
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".menu a");


// Get a reference to the video element
var v = document.querySelector("video");

// Set up click event handlers for each
Array.prototype.slice.call(anchors).forEach(function(anchor){

  anchor.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
   
     // default video when no id is present
     var d = "Gulliver.mkv";
     
     // Use the default or the id
     v.source = (!anchor.id) ? d : anchor.id + ".mkv";
     
     console.log("video source is: " + v.source);
   }); 

});
```

```html
<div class="miyazaki">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="Gulliver">Gulliver's Travels</a></li>
      <li><a id="Howl">Howl's Moving Castle</a></li>
      <li><a id="Kiki">Kiki's Delivery Service</a></li>
      <li><a id="Castle">Castle of Cagoliostro</a></li>
      <li><a id="Totoro">"My Neighbor Totoro</a></li>
      <li><a id="Ponyo">Ponyo</a></li>
      <li><a>Porco Rosso</a></li>
      <li><a id="Mononoke">"Princess Mononoke</a></li>
      <li><a id="Spirited">Spirited Away</a></li>
      <li><a id="Sky">The Sky's Castle Laputa</a></li>
      <li><a id="Nausicaa">Nausicaa Valley of the Wind</a></li>
      <li><a id="Cat">"The Cat Returns</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<video></video>
```

Comment: Would there potentially be a problem with this if within the video element there is no preset source (is it okay to leave it empty?)

Comment: @Woomfy The code will work just fine without it, but the HTML won't technically be valid. So, if validity is important to you set the source to the default value "Gulliver.mkv".

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use all these `if` blocks, you can do it in a one line statement.

You could just do it this way:

```
function Hayato() {
  var movie = $("ul.menu li a.active").attr("id");
  if(movie && movie !== "#")
      document.getElementsByClassName('window')[0].video.source.src = movie + ".mkv";
}
```

**Note:**

In the code you used all the Strings are inavlid Strings, you should wrap them between two `"` or `'`.

Comment: still not going to work because of `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @epascarello  And Porco Rosso Id's #.

Comment: Ah ok, I see it, I didn't see it in the fisrst place, I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

As you also tagged jQuery here a working example for that:

```
$('.menu li a').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.window video source').attr('src', id + '.mkv');
});
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nq6wdywy/)**

Note: Your html is invalid too. The `ul` is never closed

Comment: @Steve well if the filename is actually `#.mkv` ? Am I missing something here that I not see a problem with that?

Comment: I forgot that file and put in # as a placeholder since it stood out as a reminder to fill it in later. Sorry for the confusion